# MS Access 2010: combining consecutive date ranges

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

At work, I've been designing an MS Access query to manipulate client service agreements.
The requirement I'm stuck on is that if a client has had multiple consecutive agreements (i.e. the start date of one is the day after the end date of the previous one), they're counted as one (so the earliest start date is used).

The relevant fields in the table are:

- Agr_ID (Agreement ID), number
- Per_ID (Person ID), text
- Agr_Type (Agreement Type), text
- Start_Date, date
- End_Date, date

For example:

`103, A1234, Homecare, 20th Oct 2013, 05th Nov 2013
110, A1234, OT Equip, 06th Nov 2013, 09th Dec 2013
114, A1234, Homecare, 10th Dec 2013, 19th Jan 2014
125, A1234, Homecare, 20th Jan 2014, 15th Jun 2014
147, A1234, Homecare, 16th Jun 2014, null`

The last three would be considered a single agreement (spanning the date range 10th Dec 2013 to present) but the top two wouldn't (103 isn't consecutive with 114, 110 is of a different type). The latest agreement is to be used as the base, as subsequent queries will only keep those combined agreements whose end date is later than `[Prompt]` and which have been open for at least 365 days. So unfortunately, grabbing `min(Start_Date)` won't do.

So the desired result for that extract would be:

`103, A1234, Homecare, 20th Oct 2013, 05th Nov 2013
110, A1234, OT Equip, 06th Nov 2013, 09th Dec 2013
147, A1234, Homecare, 10th Dec 2013, null`

I'm thinking several derived tables / subqueries may be needed, to list the agreements for each client, then iteratively work backwards through the resulting table to find the earliest qualifying start date. The only consolation to the amount of recursion involved is that the table I'm basing the query on was created via a MakeTable query that filtered the raw Agreements table, so only agreements with an end date greater than `[Prompt] - 365 days` or null are included, and the Agreements table this is running off is under 10,000 records.

Comment: This would be quite hard to do in Access (possible, but difficult).  Can you use any other databases?

Comment: If you sort your data properly, perhaps a query could tell you if it is consecutive by getting the end date from the prior record, using an IIF statement and seeing if the start date of this record is +1 days. If so, set a flag saying it is consecutive.  Here is a reference to that: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210504